# Is there any PHP or JavaScript math expression formatters (which adds brackets)?

Tags: php, javascript, math, expression, string-formatting

Google Calculator formats math expressions this way:

```
2+2/2 ---> 2 + (2 / 2)
2+2/2*PI ---> 2 + ((2 / 2) * PI)
```

In others words - it adds brackets.
Are there any similar PHP or JavaScript solutions to do the same thing?

Comment: please give your question a context e.g. i want strings formatted and displayed back to the user in the browser.
is this what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: should you try an javascript event function (onkeypress, onchange)? and define the rules -- while plus signal before some number keep adding -- if division signal is found then put the brackets... but of course in somewhere someone has done the done..

Comment: @murraybiscuit: Yes, I want a javascript/PHP function that returns formatted math expression as string.

Answer (score 1):

Yes; quickest and easiest way to *not* code it yourself (like how Google did) is to use [MathML](http://www.w3.org/Math/).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

surely you could just query the calendar via curl + ajax / postback?
the result is a json array with left, right, error etc.

query example: http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?q=5*9%2B%28sqrt+10%29^3%3D

php / curl sample: http://www.dynamicguru.com/php/currency-conversion-using-php-and-google-calculator-api/#more-285